# asp:textarea control to allow the user to input text to place into the body of an e-mail

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email, webforms

I'm using an asp:textarea control to allow the user to input text and then place that text into the body of an e-mail. in the code behind, what is the syntax for adding html tags inside this text area.

For example, For my email i want to have default text to populate the text area. Some of this text is being pulled from my sql server DB.

"Dear [UserName],

The reason your booking was cancelled is because [Reason]

Kind Regards,

[LoggedIn Admin]"

The example above is the template i want to set. The [] indicate where i want to populate from my db.

So far i have been able to enter in the UserName but i cant seem to get a 
 tag to create a space to format the text properly.

The code below is what i have so far and the commented out lines are my attempts.

Id appreciate any help, Thanks

```
private void GetSelectedBooking()
        {
            //Database connection setup
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BookingDb"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);


            //Populate form with Booking Details for logged in user
            BookingId += Session["BookingId"];

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
                //preparing a query which will select all properties matching the User that is logged in at that moment
                comm.CommandText = (@"select bd.BookingId, ud.Name, bd.Date, bd.StartTime, bd.EndTime ,bd.MemberType, bd.PitchSection, bd.Description ,bd.AmountPaid , ud.Email
                                                from dbo.BookingDetails bd
                                                join UserDetail ud
                                                on ud.UserId = bd.UserId  
                                                where BookingId ='" + Session["BookingId"] + "'");
                comm.Connection = con;
                SqlDataReader rd = comm.ExecuteReader();

                if (rd.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        Booking.Text = BookingId;

                        to.Text = rd["Email"].ToString();
                        subject.Text = "Your Booking Has been Cancelled";
                        string Name = rd["Name"].ToString();
                        body.Text = "Dear " + Name.Trim() + "" +", reason";

                        //Literal ltrl = new Literal();
                        //ltrl.Text = "<BR />";

                        //body.Text = "Dear" + ltrl + Name + "reason";

                        //Literal ltrl2 = new Literal();
                        // body.Text = "<Description=" + rd["Name"].ToString() + "'><BR />View Address";
                        // e.Cell.Controls.Add(ltrl2);

                        // body.Text = "Dear " + "<BR />" + rd["Name"].ToString() + "' + reason";
                        //  body.Text = "Dear " + "<BR /> " + rd["Name"].ToString() + "'";


                    }
                }
                rd.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is only about Asp.net Webforms and html.

In order to add a line break in a Textarea control, you should use \n.

You can use a multi line string if you want to. To render a multi line string in C#, you use the @ sign, like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var message = @"Dear [UserName],

The reason your booking was cancelled is because [Reason]

Kind Regards,

[LoggedIn Admin]";

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("UserName", "johndoe");
    dictionary.Add("Reason", "you already have another booking for the same day.");
    dictionary.Add("LoggedIn Admin", "Booking Staff");

    foreach (var entry in dictionary.Keys)
    {
        message = message.Replace(string.Format("[{0}]", entry), dictionary[entry]);
    }

    // You Should now assign the message variable to the textarea.text
    // textarea.Text = message;
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

A better approach would be if you not build the text programmatically, but instead read it from a file or a database.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

I went with this solution

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47af2197-26b4-4b9e-90e8-bfa9d5cd05b4/what-is-the-deference-between-r-n-and-rn-?forum=csharplanguage

it uses /r/n to create the new line i need. so now i have:

```
to.Text = rd["Email"].ToString();
subject.Text = "Your Booking Has been Cancelled";
string Name = rd["Name"].ToString();
body.Text = "Dear " + Name.Trim() + "" +", reason" + "\r\n" + "new line test" + "\r\n" + "hi" ;
```

This outputs:
Dear [UserName], reason

new line test

hi